# TestLink 1.9.7 install - can't find config.inc.php

Tags: installation, testlink

I am trying to install TestLink 1.9.7 on my server.
I have uploaded and untarred the files.
I can access the /install/index.php web page and start the automated install.
It fails on the following:

**Checking if /var/testlink/logs/ directory exists [S]  Failed!
Checking if /var/testlink/upload_area/ directory exists [S]     Failed!**

I tried to chmod 777 these two directories, no change.

I then wanted (as suggested) to edit the config.inc.php file but I don't see it in the root of testlink where it should be.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inside testlink/ dir it will be available